# Tableau Calculated Field- Duplicated Data

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to calculate the average difference between order_time and pickup_time grouped by runner, but in customers table  order_time can appear more than once and the calculations go wrong because of this

- customers_order_table

| order_id | customer_id | pizza_id | exclusions | extras | order_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 2020-01-01 18:05:00 |
| 2 | 101 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 2020-01-01 19:01:00 |
| 3 | 102 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 2020-01-02 23:51:00 |
| 3 | 102 | 2 | NULL | NULL | 2020-01-02 23:51:00 |

-ruunners_orders_table

| order_id | runner_id | pickup_time | distance | duration | cancellation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 18:15:34 | 20 | 32 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-01 19:10:54 | 20 | 27 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | 2020-01-03 00:12:37 | 13,4 | 20 | NULL |
| 4 | 2 | 2020-01-04 13:53:03 | 23,4 | 40 | NULL |

[image: How_the calculated field is working]

My calculated field is working like (image): (9+10+21+21+15+15)/6

But it should be: (9+10+21+15)/4

It is getting 2 info about the same order

The only solution I found is to create a new table without duplicated values like this:

| order_id | runner_id | pickup_time | order_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Any other suggestion?

Comment: It seems like you may want something like `{FIXED order_id: max(pickup_time - order_time)}` because it sounds like you need a single time delta for each order. Then hopefully Tableau will let you take the average of that calculation when you have runner_id and the new field in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like you may want something like {FIXED order_id:
> max(pickup_time - order_time)} because it sounds like you need a
> single time delta for each order. Then hopefully Tableau will let you
> take the average of that calculation when you have runner_id and the
> new field in the view

[Mako212](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4421870/mako212)

I changed my calculated field from

```
DATEDIFF('minute',[Order Time],[Pickup Time])
```

to:

```sql
{ FIXED [Order Id]: max(DATEDIFF('minute',[Order Time],[Pickup Time]))}
```

Now the average calculation is correct, no more duplicates
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgD9f.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).